# How do I show downloaded videos in iOS Storage settings

Tags: ios, swift, download

I've created a streaming video app that also downloads videos locally. How can I display downloaded videos in the iPhone/iPad Storage sections of settings?

I'm downloading using background tasks, and on complete running

```
let docsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let destinationUrl = docsUrl.appendingPathComponent(videoId + ".mp4")
let fileManager = FileManager.default
try? fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationUrl)

do {
    try fileManager.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
} catch let error {
    print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
}
```

Apps like Netflix, Disney+ and Prime Video all show the downloaded shows and allow them to be deleted individually, but I haven't been able to figure out how it's done. All searches usually lead to guides for users on how to delete videos.

Anybody have any tips?

Comment: Save the destinationUrl for each video in database along with other details of the video like video title. Then in settings fetch these video items and list as you requirement. You can delete individual video by using the `fileManager.removeItem(at: video.destinationUrl)`.

Comment: @SumeshSivan I mean this for the iPhone or iPad Storage Settings, not my app settings. Currently, clicking my app in there shows 'Documents and Data', whereas the Netflix app there shows all episodes I have saved.

Comment: It is because of using .userDomainMask . This masks the items and it will only available inside the app. Use .searchPathDomainMask instead. Refer this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdomainmask/1408037-userdomainmask

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
func downloadVideo1(videoString :String)
{
    let myStringArr = videoString.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let finalString =  myStringArr[myStringArr.count - 1]
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let docsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let destinationUrl = docsUrl.appendingPathComponent(finalString)
    
    if(FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path)){
        print("\n\nfile already exists\n\n")
    }
    else{
        // setupProgress()
        //DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: videoString)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        _ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print("\n\nsome error occured\n\n")
                return
            }
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                if response.statusCode == 200{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let data = data{
                            if let _ = try? data.write(to: destinationUrl, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic){
                                print("\n\nurl data written\n\n")
                                print(destinationUrl)
                                self.checkCount = self.checkCount + 1
                                if self.checkCount == self.availableMediaCount
                                {
                                    self.progressView.isHidden = true
                                    let vc = TeacherLessonPlanSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DownloadLessonVC") as! DownloadLessonViewController
                                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                print("\n\nerror again\n\n")
                            }
                        }//end if let data
                    }//end dispatch main
                }//end if let response.status
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).